# Dealing with slightly different designs for 3.5" vs 4" iphone

Tags: ios, ios6

Are there any recommended strategies for dealing with an application that has been designed slightly differently for 4" vs 3.5" screens?
The designer has placed a couple of the objects in slightly different positions, but not in a way that seems to lend itself to layout constraints.

Other than having code that branches and adjust positions of objects, which i'd like to avoid. Are there any viable strategies for addressing this kind of situation?

Comment: Two different storyboards/xibs?  Either that, or you have a talk with your designer.  Last option you said you don't want to do:  adjust it in code.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an ideal solution and i am aware that it has, indeed, a branch, but in cases like this (only a few elements re affected by the design change) i like to create a method that returns the center for the view/control/whatever depending on the device and/or orientation. A very simple implementation of this would look like this:

```
-(CGPoint)centerForButton:(UIButton *)button{
    if([button isEqual:buttonThatNeedsRepositioning]){
        if([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568){
            //return center for 4inch-Screen
        }else{
            //return center for 3.5inch-Screen
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Now in viewDidLoad you can just assign

`buttonThatNeedsRepositioning.center = [self centerForButton: buttonThatNeedsRepositioning];`

Thats how i solved this only a few days ago, but i feel like it could be improved. Suggestions are very welcome.
Hope it helps ;)

Comment: This is definitely a good way of doing the code-branching if it does come to that. Makes it clear what it does, and at least it isolates it in those functions

Comment: Yeah, but code branching is basically more code that you need to maintain, and more potential failures when dealing with other views, animations, rotations, offsets, etc.

Comment: @Can - do you have a better idea? I'm all ears.

Comment: I'm also on the same boat, I've been maintaing old code which does this kind of thing in spades (and we can't support autolayout). The most successful approach, is sticking with resizing submasks, and, if it's not enough, writing manual positioning code, but instead of if-else, try to write them in equation form, making sure that not only A and B cases are covered, but the transition from between. In your example, a basic return `CGPoint(GetMidX, GetMidY)` is much more flexible than hard-coding it.

Comment: @Can - thanks for the reply. but i think one of us is misunderstanding the other. not sure which way it is. im not trying to find the center of a view, i am trying to set it. that means i need to do the hardcoding part, right?

Comment: @katzenhut I get what you're saying, but I'm telling you, instead of doing this `if (iphone 5) { do this } else { do that }`, inside the function you just posted, it's much more scalable to do `return CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds));` where `bounds` can be either the screen, or better, the superview.

Comment: @Can - that will get me the center of the superview. i feel like im missing simething, but i cant see what. a little help?